# ToString.Format for decimals but only if needed

Tags: string, string-formatting, vb.net-2010

I have this property value and i need its string value as its being recorded in a XML which is read from.

Now my problem is that when I do:

Example value is 1.0

```
MyProperty.StringValue.ToString
```

gives 1

how can I get this value to be in a string format but diplay the full entered 1.0

I have tried

```
MyProperty.StringValue.ToString.Format("D")
```

which gives D

bearing in mind I need any value that was entered to come out as it is ...

when I have for example 1.5 its comes back as 1.5

it only happens with 0 on the other side...

EXAMPLES

I dont understand what is exactly needed by more examples.... Its very simple....

User input is 1.0
the value is then converted to string 
and it drops the 0
so in the end is just 1
thats wrong because it is string it should reflect the value entered exactly as it is .

now if I entered 1.5
the value is then converted to string 
and in the end it comes back with 1.5 
thats ok , becuase it was entered like that

If i entered 132
the value is then converted to string 
and should and does come back as 132

hope this is enough

Comment: Please post a few different examples of inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: example if input is 1.0 I need 1.0 but 1 comes up instead.... another example when I enter 10.6 then 10.6 comes up which is fine.

Comment: Please edit your question, post 5-10 examples of inputs and outputs. Enough so we can see exactly what you need.

Comment: Edited... I wouldnt be able to give any more details .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:0.0}",MyProperty.StringValue);
```

Try this instead:

```
String.Format("{0:0.0}",MyProperty);
```

Comment: but surly that changes the format for all the other numbers ... right ?? I just want it not to drop the 0 if it was there ... its fine when I have other number beside 0

Comment: +  lobjProperty.StringValue.ToString.Format("{0:0.0}") {"Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."} System.FormatException

Comment: Fixed the code.
Give me an example of a value that is changed by this code that shouldn.t then.

Comment: I added examples in the question

Comment: thats better ... but it still comes back as 1 instead of 1.0

Comment: Why convert it to a string first anyway? Try the updated version.

Comment: Is the MyProperty where it is actually stored? Strip the `.StringValue` as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11417/discussion-between-jeroen-de-kort-and-ash-shafiee)